# Not getting the right format for "Date" in R

Tags: r, date, character

I am have a .txt data set with "Date" variable as "character"

```
 $ Date : chr  "16/12/2006" "16/12/2006" "16/12/2006" "16/12/2006" ...
```

I want to convert this variable into "Data" format. however, using both these codes:

```
energy2$Date = as.Date(energy2$Date)
```

and

```
energy2$Date = as.POSIXct (energy2$Date)
```

I get

```
$ Date : Date, format: "0016-12-20" "0016-12-20" "0016-12-20" ...
```

and

```
$ Date : POSIXct, format: "0016-12-20" "0016-12-20" ...
```

respectively.

notice the `"0016-12-20"` instead of `"16-12-2006"` I expected to see.

I am using windows 7, R version 3.3.1

Comment: `as.Date(energy2$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: `as.Date(energy2$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")` will create the proper `Date` objects. If you want them displayed differently, then you can do `format(energy2$Date, "%Y-%m-%d"")` after the conversion.

Comment: If you are curious about how the formatting works you can look at the help for the ```strptime()``` function with ```?strptime```. The date formatting specifications are explained there.